# Distribute weights across items with a smooth curve

Tags: probability-distributions, bezier-curve

Is there a function I could use to smoothly distribute a total weight *W* across *N* items with the first *K* items getting a specified percentage *P* of the weight?  For example, distribute 100 points across 100 items, with the first 10 items getting 50% of the weight.

This seems like something I could do with a (quadratic?) Bézier curve with a start of $(1,1)$ and end of $(0,0)$.  I could scale the inputs/outputs from 0 to 1, based on the number of items and weight ($x=\frac iN, w=yW$).  However, I'm not sure how to choose the control points nor whether this is a good approach.

(Apologies for the poor terminology.  Edits welcome.)

Comment: see the math of this [wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay) and then , for example, search an exponential function which has a half life of 10. It's will be very smooth, just count for the differences between integers and real numbers with decimals

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use Bézier curves, as hinted in the comments. In fact, trying to design a quadratic or cubic Bézier curve so that the point weights are integrals over equally sized strips on $[0,N]$ produces *negative* weights for some points, which would not be fancied.

Instead, to get a *really* smooth distribution use a geometric series. Let the first point have weight $a$, the second $ar$, the third $ar^2$ and so on until the last point has weight $ar^{n-1}$. Then we have
$$a\frac{1-r^N}{1-r}=W\ \text{and}\ a\frac{1-r^K}{1-r}=PW$$
where $0<P<1$. Dividing the second relation by the first produces
$$\frac{1-r^K}{1-r^N}=P$$
For the given values of $N=100,K=10$ and $P=\frac12$, *r* works out as approximately 0.933125. Substituting this into either equation allows us to derive *a*, which is approximately 6.694105.

Comment: Thank you Parcy.  I looked up the wikipedia page for geometric series and I understand that r is the ratio.  I'm afraid I don't understand how to calculate r from P however.  Would you mind adding that equation to your answer please?

Comment: That cannot be done analytically in general, because of the Abel/Ruffini theorem. I got this value by solving the equation in PARI/GP.

Comment: Does that mean my question has no answer?  I wasn't looking for the specific values I gave, but for a general solution I could apply.

Comment: It has an answer, but not an _analytic_ one. I meant that _r_ in the expression I showed above can be solved for, but only by numerical methods, not by e.g. the quadratic formula.